# Textbox within a repeater does not return values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, updatepanel, repeater

I am trying to get the value of all the textbox that is inside a repeater, but I can not.

currently the code is like this:

aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" EnableViewState="true" RenderMode="Inline" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptPagsTipoPapel" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <ul class="clrfix">
                <li>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdIdTipoPapelPubEd" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("IdTipoPapel") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTipoPapelPubEd" AssociatedControlID="txtNrPaginasCor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TipoPapel") %>'></asp:Label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="clrfix">
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Text="Páginas em Cores" AssociatedControlID="txtNrPaginasCor"></asp:Label>
                    <span class="legenda">(unidades)</span><br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNrPaginasCor" runat="server" Width="145" MaxLength="6" AutoPostBack="True"
                        ValidationGroup="vgpCadastroEdicao" OnTextChanged="txtNrPaginasCor_TextChanged" onkeypress="return(ApenasNumero(this,event));"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNrPaginasCor" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNrPaginasCor"
                        ErrorMessage="Páginas em Cores é um campo obrigatório." Display="None" ValidationGroup="valCadastroEdicao">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvlNrPaginasCor" runat="server" ErrorMessage="O campo Páginas em Cores é inválido, favor corrigí-lo."
                        ControlToValidate="txtNrPaginasCor" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" Display="None"
                        ValidationGroup="valCadastroEdicao">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvlGrupoNrPaginasCor" runat="server" ErrorMessage="O campo Páginas em Cores é inválido, favor corrigí-lo."
                        ControlToValidate="txtNrPaginasCor" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" Display="None"
                        ValidationGroup="vgpCadastroEdicao">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Text="Páginas em P/B" AssociatedControlID="txtNrPaginasPb"></asp:Label>
                    <span class="legenda">(unidades)</span><br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNrPaginasPb" runat="server" Width="145" MaxLength="6" AutoPostBack="True"
                        ValidationGroup="vgpCadastroEdicao" OnTextChanged="txtNrPaginasPb_TextChanged" onkeypress="return(ApenasNumero(this,event));"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNrPaginasPb" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNrPaginasPb"
                        ErrorMessage="Páginas em P/B é um campo obrigatório." Display="None" ValidationGroup="valCadastroEdicao">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvlNrPaginasPb" runat="server" ErrorMessage="O campo Páginas em P/B é inválido, favor corrigí-lo."
                        ControlToValidate="txtNrPaginasPb" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" Display="None"
                        ValidationGroup="valCadastroEdicao">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvlGrupoNrPaginasPb" runat="server" ErrorMessage="O campo Páginas em P/B é inválido, favor corrigí-lo."
                        ControlToValidate="txtNrPaginasPb" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" Display="None"
                        ValidationGroup="vgpCadastroEdicao">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
 </ContentTemplate>
```

Excerpt related to code-behind Text Changed event, I need to trigger this event to calculate a value to be displayed to the user so dynamic.

```
    Protected Sub txtNrPaginasCor_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MostrarCustoProducaoPublicacao()
End Sub

Protected Sub txtNrPaginasPb_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MostrarCustoProducaoPublicacao()
End Sub
```

Piece of code where I want to take values ​​from textboxes:

```
Protected Sub MostrarCustoProducaoPublicacao()
    Dim lIntTiragem As Integer = Nothing
    Dim lIntNrPaginasPbJornal As Integer = Nothing
    Dim lIntNrPaginasCorJornal As Integer = Nothing
    Dim lIntNrPaginasPbOffset As Integer = Nothing
    Dim lIntNrPaginasCorOffset As Integer = Nothing
    Dim IdPublicacao As Integer = SQL.RetiraSQLInjection(hdIdPublicacao.Value)


        For Each itemTipoPapel As RepeaterItem In rptPagsTipoPapel.Items
            Dim hdTipoPapel As HiddenField = CType(itemTipoPapel.FindControl("hdIdTipoPapelPubEd"), HiddenField)
            Dim txtNrPagPB As TextBox = CType(itemTipoPapel.FindControl("txtNrPaginasPb"), TextBox)

            Dim txtNrPagCor As TextBox = CType(itemTipoPapel.FindControl("txtNrPaginasCor"), TextBox)
            If hdTipoPapel.Value = 1 Or hdTipoPapel.Value = 2 Then
                If Not txtNrPagPB.Text.Equals("") Then
                    lIntNrPaginasPbJornal += SQL.RetiraSQLInjection(txtNrPagPB.Text)
                End If
                If Not txtNrPagCor.Text.Equals("") Then
                    lIntNrPaginasCorJornal += SQL.RetiraSQLInjection(txtNrPagCor.Text)
                End If
            ElseIf hdTipoPapel.Value = 3 Or hdTipoPapel.Value = 4 Then
                If Not txtNrPagPB.Text.Equals("") Then
                    lIntNrPaginasPbOffset += SQL.RetiraSQLInjection(txtNrPagPB.Text)
                End If
                If Not txtNrPagCor.Text.Equals("") Then
                    lIntNrPaginasCorOffset += SQL.RetiraSQLInjection(txtNrPagCor.Text)
                End If
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean that you "cannot get the value"? What happens when you try to get it?

Comment: So @Johnsaunders, running debug, the textbox is found, but the Text property is coming empty.

Comment: In what event are you checking Text? Try adding a TextBox outside of the repeater and see if the new TextBox keeps its value.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm checking the text value inside the for each in the last code snippet posted.
I tested adding a TextBox after the repeater and the value remained.

Comment: So this is on the TextChanged event? And your method is definitely being called?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, but I need get values ​​of all TextBox in repeater for performing the calculation and not just the current TextBox, is possible?

Comment: Have you tried getting the value in the PreRender event? I'm just trying to narrow down the problem. Also, please show your Page_Load code. Are you data-binding the data in Page_Load even on a postback?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there isn't any even rebinding your repeater before your textChanged event's triggers, as for eg. pageLoad.
If somethins it's binding your repeater you won't be able to get any of these values.